# How to get child elements using NightwatchJs

Tags: nightwatch.js

How can I get child element of a dropdown using nightwatch js. here is my code

```
<ul id="ddEmp" class="ng-scope">
    <li class="ng-scope active">Emp 1</li>
    <li class="ng-scope">Emp 2</li>
    <li class="ng-scope">Emp 3</li>
</ul>
```

I want to get "Emp 3".

Answer (score 2):

you can use the nth-child() css selector. In your case it would be ul#ddEmp li:nth-child(3)

You can also use xpath and look for the text in the li:

.useXpath().click('//li[text()="Emp 3"]')